# square root of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to calculate the square root of a matrix that may be after no positive defined by using MATLAB(so I cannot use chol instruction) . Somewhere I saw the function nearestspd  but I can not find it in MATLAB . Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Per https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sqrtm.html , in MATLAB, X = sqrtm(A) returns the principal square root of the matrix A, that is, X*X = A.

This is defined for any matrix A, positive definite or not, but may have complex entries (for instance, think of the 1 by 1 matrix "-1").